# JavaFx: Check if mouse is over a node's children

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

JavaFx: I have a HBox with a Button in it ,inside a Group, and I would like to manage the "MousePressed" event differently for each node.
At the moment if I handle the same event for all the nodes, it is always catches by the parent node (Group).

Is there a way to do that?
For example is there a way to determine if the mouse coordinates are over the node's children (HBox in my example)?

This is an example of what I need:

[image]

If I click on Group I want to hide the HBox if the coordinate of mouse don't collide with HBox,  If I click on HBox, Hbox doesn't need to be hide, and If I click on the Button (implemented as an ImageView)  I need to execute code without hide the HBox.

So for example what I would like to do is something like that:

```
    '
Group group= new Group();
HBox hBox = new HBox();
ImageView image= new ImageView();
hBox.getChildren().add(image);
hBox.toFront();
group.getChildren().add(hBox);
image.setImage(ImageUtil.getImage("img.png"));
group.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                        <if not collide with HBOX hide HBOX.>

                    }
                });
box.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                        <do other things without hidding HBOX.>

                    }
                });



image.onMouseClickedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                @Override
                                public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        <do something>
                                    }

                            });
```

'
Where group is inside an AncorPane designed with sceneBuilder
'

```
@FXML
Group group;
```

'

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just register different handlers with each of the child nodes. Maybe it would help to post some code.

Comment: I have already registered two handlers one for the parent (Group) and one for the children (HBox), the problem is that everything is caught by the first (one linked to Group)....

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. It's difficult (perhaps impossible) to know what's going wrong without a code example.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have updated my question, I hope it is more clear.

Comment: Not really: it's not really possible to understand what's happening without the layout code. Please write a [MCVE].

Comment: I have updated again, with how the layout is created... I hope this time it is better... I cannot provide a verifiable example ( I would need to attach the scene builder xml and all the rest), but I think now should be enough

Comment: voting to close .. it's **ALWAYS** possible to provide an example (as described in the reference given by @James_D ) that demonstrates a problem. Without, any answer is a guessing game that's wasting everybody's time.

Comment: On top of that, the code presented doesn't generate the layout shown in the diagram. A `Group` takes on the union of the bounds of its child nodes, so with the code given there is no part of the `Group` that does not contain the `HBox`.

Comment: I agree, please close it and I will try to open a new one providing a SSCCE. Thank you in any case for all your answers and your patience...

Comment: Done,  you can find the new one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887546/javafx-check-if-the-mouse-is-on-nodes-children

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but nontheless, if it helps you:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// the magic: use setPickOnBounds(false);
public class LayersWithMouseEvents extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // root
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        // layers
        Pane bottomLayer = new Pane();
        Pane topLayer = new Pane();

        // bottom: layer1, top: layer2
        root.getChildren().addAll(bottomLayer, topLayer);

        // layer 1 objects
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle( 100,100,100,100);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        rectangle.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Rectangle 0: " + e));
        bottomLayer.getChildren().add(rectangle);

        // layer 2 objects
        rectangle = new Rectangle( 50,50,50,50);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.RED);
        rectangle.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Rectangle 1: " + e));
        topLayer.getChildren().add(rectangle);

        rectangle = new Rectangle( 125,125,50,50);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.RED);
        rectangle.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Rectangle 2: " + e));
        topLayer.getChildren().add(rectangle);

        rectangle = new Rectangle( 200,200,50,50);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.RED);
        rectangle.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Rectangle 3: " + e));
        topLayer.getChildren().add(rectangle);

        // layer 1 event handler
        bottomLayer.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Layer 1: " + e));

        // layer 2 event handler
        topLayer.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Layer 2: " + e));


        // this is the magic that allows you to click on the layer1 object event though layer 2 is on top of layer 1
        // but ONLY(!) as long as the layer is transparent. if you add e. g. this it won't work anymore to click through to layer 1:
        //   layer2.setStyle( "-fx-background-color:yellow");
        topLayer.setPickOnBounds(false);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Another example would be to add the listener to the parent, e. g. the scene and check the event's target like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LayersWithMouseEvents2 extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle( 100,100,100,100);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow");
        hBox.getChildren().add( rectangle);

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(hBox);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

        primaryStage.getScene().setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Scene: " + e));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Depending on where you click you get:

```
Scene: MouseEvent [source = javafx.scene.Scene@2c69fd61, target = javafx.scene.Scene@2c69fd61, eventType = MOUSE_PRESSED, consumed = false, x = 295.0, y = 134.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, primaryButtonDown, pickResult = PickResult [node = null, point = Point3D [x = 295.0, y = 134.0, z = 0.0], distance = 1119.6152422706632]
Scene: MouseEvent [source = javafx.scene.Scene@2c69fd61, target = HBox@5a40dda8, eventType = MOUSE_PRESSED, consumed = false, x = 148.0, y = 134.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, primaryButtonDown, pickResult = PickResult [node = HBox@5a40dda8, point = Point3D [x = 148.0, y = 134.0, z = 0.0], distance = 1119.6152422706632]
Scene: MouseEvent [source = javafx.scene.Scene@2c69fd61, target = Rectangle[x=100.0, y=100.0, width=100.0, height=100.0, fill=0x008000ff], eventType = MOUSE_PRESSED, consumed = false, x = 52.0, y = 54.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, primaryButtonDown, pickResult = PickResult [node = Rectangle[x=100.0, y=100.0, width=100.0, height=100.0, fill=0x008000ff], point = Point3D [x = 152.0, y = 154.0, z = 0.0], distance = 1119.6152422706632]
```

And with the visibility toggling it could be like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LayersWithMouseEvents2 extends Application {

    boolean hBoxVisible = true;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle( 100,100,100,100);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow");
        hBox.getChildren().add( rectangle);

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> {

            System.out.println("Scene: " + e);

            if( e.getTarget() == hBox) {
                System.out.println( "HBox clicked");
            }

            if( e.getTarget() == rectangle) {
                System.out.println( "Rectangle clicked");
            }

            if( e.getTarget() == scene) {
                System.out.println( "Scene clicked");

                hBoxVisible = !hBoxVisible;

                hBox.setVisible(hBoxVisible);}

        });

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer But this is not what I need I have updated my question adding an example of what I need..

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: @navy1978 that's exactly why a SSCCE is required: without, it's a guessing game of what exactly you want to achieve and how exactly your code goes wrong. Note that it **ALWAYS** possible to provide such an example that's stripped down to the barest minimum that demonstrates a problem!